# RTD temperature measurement system resistance question

Tags: sensor, bridge, rtd

[image]

I am trying to produce a bridge circuit for the following temperature measurement system:

- Designed to measure temperatures between 0 C and 100 C with a high accuracy.
- When supplied with a 10 V source voltage, the system produces an output ranging from 0 mV to 100 mV.

I have chosen a PT100 platinum RTD sensor for this circuit (which I am presuming will be a 3 wire Wheatstone bridge).

1. What would the resistances be of R1, R2, R3 and R4?
2. What would happen if I varied those resistances? (all of them equal or R3 & R4 being much larger/smaller than R1 & R2)
3. And then how would I calculate the current through this RTD Sensor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You know the resistance changes by 38.5\$\Omega\$ (assuming a DIN-standard Pt100 sensor) for your desired range, so you should be able to calculate the current required, the resistance on your bridge half to balance at 100\$\Omega\$/0°C and calculate the effect of leadwire resistance changes.

Nobody would make an RTD front end like this in 2019. The required sensor current too high (leading to excessive self-heating), correction for leadwire resistances is imperfect etc. Presumably this is a homework problem, so if you want additional help, please show your work.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely agree with @Spehro Pefhany.

But If you need a straight forward answer to your Question,

1. R1 = R2 = 3607.66 Ohms.
   R3 = 100 Ohms.
   R4 is your Pt100.
   (As per the labels of your diagram)

   If these values are exact, you will get your desired 0-100mV difference between Vb.
2. The common mode voltage of your 0-100mV output would vary. Also, your output would not remain 0-100mV if you change R1 and R2. Keep in mind the proportion of R1: R4(Pt100):: R2: R3 Decide the Voltage Vb.

   Keeping them All 100 Ohms would give you a very large difference at Vb but when the bridge would draw a lot of current and self-heating would introduce errors.
   Vary R2 and R3 in such a way you disturb the proportion and the initial value Vb at 0°C will not be 0V (bridge imbalance).
3. To evaluate the voltage and current at / different points use KCV and KVL.
   The Resistors That fit your requirement would result in a 2.7mA Current through the sensor. Which, is kind of a bit more considering how power efficient '2019 manufacturers' make these sensor transmitters.

Feel free to comment to ask for any further query.